# Destroy process in java

Tags: java

I created a class that starts and ends a process in java. I tried mspaint.exe with or without args and it starts the process,
but when I tried to start calculator(calc.exe) it doesn't work.
Is there a reason it will only start specific processes?

```
public class XProcess {

    private Process process;
    private String cmd;

    public XProcess(String command) {
        this.cmd = command;
    }
    public synchronized void start() throws IOException{
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.cmd);
    }
    public synchronized void destroy(){
        process.destroy();
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        XProcess process = new XProcess("mspaint.exe");
        process.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        process.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Please improve your question quality. You can find more tips in: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages.

Comment: not getting an error but it seems like calculator not exited

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for Process's `destroy()` explains it quite nicely

> Kills the subprocess. Whether the subprocess represented by this
>   Process object is forcibly terminated or not is implementation
>   dependent.

Generally, an attempt to destroy (or kill) a process is a request.  The Operating System could intercept the request, or the process itself could refuse the request.

The proper way to shutdown a process is for the process to internally quit, with the parent process (the one that launched the child process) listening for the child's exit.  Anything else tends to be spotty as to whether it will work in all cases, with all processes.

This is why many processes (Tomcat is an example) accept a shutdown command as a network request, so it can then handle the request, shutting down internally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some recent Windows? 10 or probably even 8?
Then it's unrelated to Java, the new Calculator is a Windows Store app, calc.exe is probably just a wrapper that starts it in a new container process and exists right after that, it's gone by the time you try to destroy it.